# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when inserting into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program that at some point needs to put 2 arrays of different lengths into a 2 dimensional array.

Does anyone know why I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the specified line?

```
String[][] proteinArray;

if(proteinsMomFinal.length > proteinsDadFinal.length)
{
    proteinArray = new String[proteinsMomFinal.length][2];
}
else
{
    proteinArray = new String[proteinsDadFinal.length][2];
}

for(int i = 0; i < proteinsMom.length; i++)
{
    proteinArray[i][0] = proteinsMomFinal[i];          // error is here
}

for(int i = 0; i < proteinsDad.length; i++)
{
    proteinArray[i][1] = proteinsDadFinal[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where proteinsMom, proteinsDad, proteinsMomFinal and proteinsDadFinal are declared?  There seems to be critical information missing from this code snippet

Comment: Run in debugger mode , put a breakpoint and check for yourself !

Comment: What is the value of `i` when the error occurs? What is the value of `proteinsMomFinal.length`?

Comment: No way to say from the code we see, however it's probably that proteinsMomFinal.length != proteinsMom.length.

Comment: You know, if you look at the exception message it will tell you what line the error occurs on.  Then with debugger or println statements you can examine the array sizes and the index values.

Comment: This could be one of many things, but it will be impossible for us to guess without more info.  The best thing you could do is learn how to troubleshoot issues like this on your own by reading the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using proteinsMomFinal in the for statement. How can you know that the proteinsMom is the same length as proteinsMomFinal?

```
for(int i = 0; i < proteinsMomFinal.length; i++)
{
    proteinArray[i][0] = proteinsMomFinal[i];          // error is here
}
```